# Downscaling global meteorology data

Tags: meteorology, wrf

Can some one explain me the basics of downscaling (interpolate to a smaller cell) a global meteorology data to a local scale (2 km × 2 km). IF would be very thankful if you provide a link at least. is it possible? Main variables are U<sub>x</sub> U<sub>y</sub>, temperature, pressure.

Comment: Please expand your question to include the variables of interest and the size of your "local scale."

Comment: by downscaling to you mean interpolating between existing points? Or is it already in a "grid" and you want to resample it to a smaller cell size? Or something else. There are several questions on [gis.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=resampling).

Comment: Check this [article](http://idl.ul.pt/sites/idl.ul.pt/files/docs/SoaresEtal_CDyn_2012.pdf) about `WRF high resolution dynamical downscaling`